# Handling gesture recognizers in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uigesturerecognizer

Apparently iOS 6 tries to automatically handle the situation when you have a gesture recognizer and a `UIButton` in the same place, being activated for the same gesture.

This new automatic handling solves the issue when you want to click the button instead of activating the gesture recognizer, but **creates a new problem** when you want the gesture recognizer to act.

In iOS 5 you could implement:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

to transfer the action to the `UIButton` when in a conflict.

This doesn't seem to work in iOS 6. Also, inverting the behavior of this method (because now the `UIButton` has the priority instead of the gesture recognizer) won't work.

---

Complete method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you have a uigesturerecognizer on a uiview which has a uibutton subview and want the gesture recognizer to get touches instead of the button?

Comment: yes. Actually its a `UITableView` with `UIButtons` within the cells, and I want the gesture recognizer to be activated instead of the buttons.

Comment: Hasn't iOS done this all the way back to its origin? I've always had problems hitting under a button.

Comment: Exact same issue with me. If I run my app on iOS5 and tap over the button added over View with tap gesture added, the handleTap method is called while if I run the same app on iOS6 device handleTap is not getting called. I have not overridden shouldReceiveTouch. Do I need to add target  on UIButton for UIControlEventTouchUpInside specifically for iOS6 ?

Comment: I added target on UIButton for UIControlEventTouchUpInside and it solved my purpose. On iOS6 the target selector is called and on iOS5 handleTap from where I am calling the same selector.

Comment: Would you create an answer explaining this fix?

Comment: What event do you use to trigger actions on the buttons? It almost always should be on UIControlEventTouchUpInside. It gives the system the chance to handle gestures, and it gives the user the chance to correct tapping mistakes.

Comment: So to disable the gesture recognizer I would have to use like... touch down?

Comment: It is not very clear from your question what is your exact layout. Can I ask why do you need or why do you have a gesture recognizer and a UIButton in the same place?? Specially when you only want the gesture recognizer to get touches not the button. Could you not get rid of the buttons and solve your issue??

Comment: This issue is agnostic and not specific to my layout.

Comment: Yes  Júlio, I understand that is so. At the same time I was more interested in knowing why the need of having a gesture recognizer and a UIButton in the same place in the app, if you don't mind.

Comment: I was working in an app that had several buttons inside UITableViewCells, so there were like 18 buttons in the screen. Each button opens a "popup" that displays some data, and when you tap away from the popup, it would hide. I fixed the issue with ios6 by placing a huge-ridiculous transparent button in the back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this to workaround the issue, change it as you see fit:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
      [self MyCommonSelector];// this will work for ios 5
      return Yes;
 }
```

Add target in button where you declare so this will call in iOS 6:

```
[self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MyCommonSelector)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Do your stuff in this method which will also be called on button tap and from the gesture you need to call:

```
-(void)MyCommonSelector
 {
    //Do your stuff here what you want to do with Gesture too.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't know why you would put UIButtons there if you don't want them to be tapped, you can prevent subviews from receiving touches by overriding the `-hitTest:withEvent:` method of your containing view.

`-hitTest:withEvent:` by default returns the *"farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point"*, so by default, when tapping one of the buttons, your containing view would return the button.

Your implementation should look something like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)aPoint withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:aPoint]) {
        return self;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

So if your container view this is being called on contains the point of the touch, it returns itself and the gesture recognizer attached to it will get the touch.

Because this implementation never returns any subview, none of the UIButtons will ever get a chance to respond to the touches.

Comment: I have a button in the "popup" I'm hiding via this method. This button wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems simplistic, but have you considered setting the UIButton's userInteractionEnabled property to "NO"? That should remove it automatically from the hit testing and gesture recognition system.

Comment: Why is that? You haven't explained why this doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: I have about 16 buttons built programatically that can change, I do not have the reference to all of them where I'm issuing the subview and I'm pretty sure there is some wiser way to do that, I'm not in a hurry.