# iPhone 5.0 and 5.1 Simulators Not Calling IBActions?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an app with a target of iOS 5.0. Unfortunately, I no longer have any test devices with iOS 5.

I'd like to be able to use the iOS 5.0 and 5.1 simulators to do basic debugging, but for some reason, my `IBAction`s aren't being called on these simulators.

Further info:

- Xcode version is 4.5.2
- All simulators are up-to-date (no pending updates/downloads available)
- We do have customers who use iOS 5 and 5.1, and they don't have any issues clicking the buttons (or at least, we haven't received any reports about such from them ; )
- On the iPhone 6.0 simulator, everything works as expected (pretty sure all `IBActions` are connected correctly)

Are these simulators just terribly buggy (is this a known issue)? Have others ran into this issue and know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a `UITapGesture` on `self.view` was capturing the touches and NOT forwarding to the subviews... for some reason, this behavior appears to be different in iOS 6 and iOS 5 simulators... user beware...

Comment: Here's a good SO post that explains what was going on and possible ways to tackle this change in behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518328/handling-gesture-recognizers-in-ios6

Answer (score 1):

Most Probably issue i seen that..

- might be you not define your `IBAction` method in .h file.
- might be you connect two `IBAction` on one `UIButton` `TouchUpInside`.
- you also try uninstall app from simulatore clear xcode than might be solve your issue.
- reset you simulator contain.
- Check is any update of `Xcode` then you try to run your app then you got solution.

I am working on same configuration and i have no issue like yours..

Comment: Are you required to define `IBAction`s in the header file? You're right in that I sometimes define them in a private `interface` within the implementation file... I'll try moving these to header and see if this makes a difference...

Comment: Thanks for the tips... it turned out to be an issue with how UITapGestures are handled differently in iOS 5 versus iOS 6 simulator... : /

Answer (score 0):

Use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to avoid effect of gestureRecognizer on a selectedView:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    UIView *selectedView = self.view;

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view.superview];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(selectedView.frame, point)) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```